# Getting 0's and 1's of a file from bash

Tags: bash

It seems that neither `hexdump` or `od` have support for output in binary representation. Is there any other built-in way of doing this?

I'm trying to draw a black/white bitmap onto the terminal, so I thought the easiest way would be to just output the bits with line breaks after each row.

Comment: How do you know where a line ends?

Comment: data is actually from a png, so I have header info separately. No magic! :-)

Comment: Are you trying to get a representation of the image in the terminal? If that's the case, you might want to investigate algorithms for producing ASCII art from images.

Answer (score 2):

```
xxd -b input_file
```

will give you a binary representation of the file as ones and zeros.

You could use the `-c` flag to specify how many bytes you want displayed in each "row".

You'll probably need to do some post-processing if you just want the ones and zeros as each line is prepended with a line number and appended with the original binary data.

As an example, you could do something like:

```
xxd -c 4 -b input_file | awk '{print $2 $3 $4 $5}'
```

to get the output I think you're after.

**Edit**

I notice a subsequent comment indicates you're trying to represent a `png` file. If you're after a pictorial representation of the image, you'll probably want to investigate algorithms for producing ASCII art from images automatically.

Just for fun, you could add the following:

```
xxd -c 4 -b input_file | awk '{print $2 $3 $4 $5}'| sed 's/1/·/g; s/0/ /g'
```

to get a slightly more visual representation.

Comment: Nice! I like `awk` for this; my first thought was `xxd -b -c4 input_file | cut -d' ' -f2-5 | sed -e 's/ //g'` but yours is better.

Comment: Thanks. Depending on the number of bytes selected per line for the output, your solution might prove more elegant, because I don't know of a succinct way to specify printing of a range of column with `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with `xxd`:

```
xxd -b input
```